# Is there any version of Vim which uses the libxft library to render fonts?

Tags: vim

Is there any version of Vim which uses the libxft library to render fonts?

Comment: Vim doesn't render fonts. The terminal emulator does. So your question should be: does any terminal emulator use the libxft library to render fonts?

Answer (score 1):

GVim users FreeType to render fonts.